# Importing OpenCV in Cmake Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, nvidia-jetson

Not really familiar how cmake and the packages are been resolve in ubuntu.

I have the next file cmake for ROS systemm.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.3)
project(moveit_calibration_plugins)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

if(NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rosconsole
  tf2
  tf2_eigen
  tf2_geometry_msgs
  pluginlib
  sensor_msgs
)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED imgcodecs aruco)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS
    handeye_calibration_target/include
    handeye_calibration_solver/include
  LIBRARIES
    # No libraries are exported because directly linking to a plugin is "highly discouraged":
    # http://wiki.ros.org/class_loader#Caution_of_Linking_Directly_Against_Plugin_Libraries
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    roscpp
    sensor_msgs
  DEPENDS
    EIGEN3
)

include_directories(
                    handeye_calibration_target/include
                    handeye_calibration_solver/include
                    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    )
include_directories(SYSTEM
                    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    )

add_subdirectory(handeye_calibration_target)
add_subdirectory(handeye_calibration_solver)

install(
  FILES
    handeye_calibration_target_plugin_description.xml
    handeye_calibration_solver_plugin_description.xml
  DESTINATION
    ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

I had to compile my own OpenCV since I am using Nvidia Jetson. I managed to install them in `/usr/local/src` both `OpenCV` and `OpenCV-contrib`.

I resolved manually inside the cmake so it can find OpenCV changing.
from:

```
find_package(OpenCV 4.1.1 EXACT REQUIRED imgcodecs aruco)
```

to:

```
find_package(OpenCV 4.1.1 EXACT REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/lib imgcodecs aruco)
```

The issue is then that the aruco can not be find.

```
    /home/ros/alfredonator/edo_ws/src/moveit_calibration/moveit_calibration_gui/handeye_calibration_rviz_plugin
/include/moveit/handeye_calibration_rviz_plugin/handeye_target_widget.h:57:29: fatal error: opencv2/aruco.hpp: 
No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Running `pkg-config --libs opencv` I see that is pointing to `/usr/local/lib` instead of `/usr/local/src`. Is that the issue why the cmake is not failing to find OpenCV but the next module fails to find aruco?

/usr/local/src

```
├── opencv-4.1.1
│   ├── 3rdparty
│   ├── apps
│   ├── cmake
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│   ├── data
│   ├── doc
│   ├── include
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── modules
│   ├── platforms
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── release
│   └── samples
├── opencv-4.1.1.zip
├── opencv_contrib-4.1.1
│   ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│   ├── doc
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── modules
│   ├── README.md
│   └── samples
└── opencv_contrib-4.1.1.zip
```

/usr/local/lib

```
.
├── cmake
├── libfw.a
├── libglfw3.a
├── libopencv_aruco.so -> libopencv_aruco.so.4.1
├── libopencv_aruco.so.4.1 -> libopencv_aruco.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_aruco.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_bgsegm.so -> libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.1
├── libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.1 -> libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_bioinspired.so -> libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.1
├── libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.1 -> libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_calib3d.so -> libopencv_calib3d.so.4.1
├── libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4 -> libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_calib3d.so.4.1 -> libopencv_calib3d.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_calib3d.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_ccalib.so -> libopencv_ccalib.so.4.1
├── libopencv_ccalib.so.4.1 -> libopencv_ccalib.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_ccalib.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_core.so -> libopencv_core.so.4.1
├── libopencv_core.so.3.4 -> libopencv_core.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_core.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_core.so.4.1 -> libopencv_core.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_core.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudaarithm.so -> libopencv_cudaarithm.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudaarithm.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudaarithm.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudaarithm.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudabgsegm.so -> libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudacodec.so -> libopencv_cudacodec.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudacodec.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudacodec.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudacodec.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudacodec.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudacodec.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudacodec.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so -> libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudafilters.so -> libopencv_cudafilters.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudafilters.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudafilters.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudafilters.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudaimgproc.so -> libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudalegacy.so -> libopencv_cudalegacy.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudalegacy.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudalegacy.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudalegacy.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudalegacy.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudalegacy.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudalegacy.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so -> libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudaoptflow.so -> libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudastereo.so -> libopencv_cudastereo.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudastereo.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudastereo.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudastereo.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudastereo.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudastereo.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudastereo.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudawarping.so -> libopencv_cudawarping.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudawarping.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudawarping.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudawarping.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudev.so -> libopencv_cudev.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cudev.so.3.4 -> libopencv_cudev.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudev.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_cudev.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cudev.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cudev.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cvv.so -> libopencv_cvv.so.4.1
├── libopencv_cvv.so.4.1 -> libopencv_cvv.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_cvv.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_datasets.so -> libopencv_datasets.so.4.1
├── libopencv_datasets.so.4.1 -> libopencv_datasets.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_datasets.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so -> libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.4.1
├── libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.4.1 -> libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_dnn.so -> libopencv_dnn.so.4.1
├── libopencv_dnn.so.3.4 -> libopencv_dnn.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_dnn.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_dnn.so.4.1 -> libopencv_dnn.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_dnn.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_dpm.so -> libopencv_dpm.so.4.1
├── libopencv_dpm.so.4.1 -> libopencv_dpm.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_dpm.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_face.so -> libopencv_face.so.4.1
├── libopencv_face.so.4.1 -> libopencv_face.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_face.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_features2d.so -> libopencv_features2d.so.4.1
├── libopencv_features2d.so.3.4 -> libopencv_features2d.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_features2d.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_features2d.so.4.1 -> libopencv_features2d.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_features2d.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_flann.so -> libopencv_flann.so.4.1
├── libopencv_flann.so.3.4 -> libopencv_flann.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_flann.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_flann.so.4.1 -> libopencv_flann.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_flann.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_freetype.so -> libopencv_freetype.so.4.1
├── libopencv_freetype.so.4.1 -> libopencv_freetype.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_freetype.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_fuzzy.so -> libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.1
├── libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.1 -> libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_gapi.so -> libopencv_gapi.so.4.1
├── libopencv_gapi.so.4.1 -> libopencv_gapi.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_gapi.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_hdf.so -> libopencv_hdf.so.4.1
├── libopencv_hdf.so.4.1 -> libopencv_hdf.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_hdf.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_hfs.so -> libopencv_hfs.so.4.1
├── libopencv_hfs.so.4.1 -> libopencv_hfs.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_hfs.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_highgui.so -> libopencv_highgui.so.4.1
├── libopencv_highgui.so.3.4 -> libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_highgui.so.4.1 -> libopencv_highgui.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_highgui.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_imgcodecs.so -> libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1
├── libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 -> libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 -> libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_img_hash.so -> libopencv_img_hash.so.4.1
├── libopencv_img_hash.so.4.1 -> libopencv_img_hash.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_img_hash.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_imgproc.so -> libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1
├── libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 -> libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 -> libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_line_descriptor.so -> libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.1
├── libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.1 -> libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_ml.so -> libopencv_ml.so.4.1
├── libopencv_ml.so.3.4 -> libopencv_ml.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_ml.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_ml.so.4.1 -> libopencv_ml.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_ml.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_objdetect.so -> libopencv_objdetect.so.4.1
├── libopencv_objdetect.so.3.4 -> libopencv_objdetect.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_objdetect.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_objdetect.so.4.1 -> libopencv_objdetect.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_objdetect.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_optflow.so -> libopencv_optflow.so.4.1
├── libopencv_optflow.so.4.1 -> libopencv_optflow.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_optflow.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so -> libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.1
├── libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.1 -> libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_photo.so -> libopencv_photo.so.4.1
├── libopencv_photo.so.3.4 -> libopencv_photo.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_photo.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_photo.so.4.1 -> libopencv_photo.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_photo.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_plot.so -> libopencv_plot.so.4.1
├── libopencv_plot.so.4.1 -> libopencv_plot.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_plot.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_quality.so -> libopencv_quality.so.4.1
├── libopencv_quality.so.4.1 -> libopencv_quality.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_quality.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_reg.so -> libopencv_reg.so.4.1
├── libopencv_reg.so.4.1 -> libopencv_reg.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_reg.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_rgbd.so -> libopencv_rgbd.so.4.1
├── libopencv_rgbd.so.4.1 -> libopencv_rgbd.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_rgbd.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_saliency.so -> libopencv_saliency.so.4.1
├── libopencv_saliency.so.4.1 -> libopencv_saliency.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_saliency.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_shape.so -> libopencv_shape.so.4.1
├── libopencv_shape.so.3.4 -> libopencv_shape.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_shape.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_shape.so.4.1 -> libopencv_shape.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_shape.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_stereo.so -> libopencv_stereo.so.4.1
├── libopencv_stereo.so.4.1 -> libopencv_stereo.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_stereo.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_stitching.so -> libopencv_stitching.so.4.1
├── libopencv_stitching.so.3.4 -> libopencv_stitching.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_stitching.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_stitching.so.4.1 -> libopencv_stitching.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_stitching.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_structured_light.so -> libopencv_structured_light.so.4.1
├── libopencv_structured_light.so.4.1 -> libopencv_structured_light.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_structured_light.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_superres.so -> libopencv_superres.so.4.1
├── libopencv_superres.so.3.4 -> libopencv_superres.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_superres.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_superres.so.4.1 -> libopencv_superres.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_superres.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_surface_matching.so -> libopencv_surface_matching.so.4.1
├── libopencv_surface_matching.so.4.1 -> libopencv_surface_matching.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_surface_matching.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_text.so -> libopencv_text.so.4.1
├── libopencv_text.so.4.1 -> libopencv_text.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_text.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_tracking.so -> libopencv_tracking.so.4.1
├── libopencv_tracking.so.4.1 -> libopencv_tracking.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_tracking.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_videoio.so -> libopencv_videoio.so.4.1
├── libopencv_videoio.so.3.4 -> libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_videoio.so.4.1 -> libopencv_videoio.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_videoio.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_video.so -> libopencv_video.so.4.1
├── libopencv_video.so.3.4 -> libopencv_video.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_video.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_video.so.4.1 -> libopencv_video.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_video.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_videostab.so -> libopencv_videostab.so.4.1
├── libopencv_videostab.so.3.4 -> libopencv_videostab.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_videostab.so.3.4.0
├── libopencv_videostab.so.4.1 -> libopencv_videostab.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_videostab.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_xfeatures2d.so -> libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.1
├── libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.1 -> libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_ximgproc.so -> libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.1
├── libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.1 -> libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_xobjdetect.so -> libopencv_xobjdetect.so.4.1
├── libopencv_xobjdetect.so.4.1 -> libopencv_xobjdetect.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_xobjdetect.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_xphoto.so -> libopencv_xphoto.so.4.1
├── libopencv_xphoto.so.4.1 -> libopencv_xphoto.so.4.1.1
├── libopencv_xphoto.so.4.1.1
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you posted your full CMakeLists.txt. You should construct an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you linking the imported targets from those `find_package` calls to your targets via `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: Also, don't use `PATHS`. It's meant to be used for only _computed_ paths (ie. you find something the normal way and then need to find something related to it). Set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to include `/usr/local` via the `-D` command line.

Comment: @AlexReinking Hi Alex, thanks for taking your time. I have added the complete cmake file.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're not linking OpenCV to your targets. Basically any time you use `include_directories`, you're doing something wrong. You should link to Eigen via `target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)` similarly, you should use OpenCV's imported targets, whatever they are.

Comment: It's also _very weird_ to install things to `/usr/local/src`. I'm not sure what the deal is with pkg-config, but CMake doesn't use it to find things (unless you explicitly use the compatibility module, which you aren't).

Comment: The OpenCV targets are named `opencv_<module>`, so try linking to `opencv_aruco`